# EasyAdminBundle entity form fields customization

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I am trying to make a standard "created_at" field readonly in the edit form. Following [the doc](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/getting-started/4-views-and-actions.md#customize-the-properties-appearance) you have to add the following configuration:

```
    MyEntity:
        form:
            fields:
                - { property: 'created_at', type_options: { widget: 'single_text' } }
```

But it throws the following error:

```
An Exception was thrown while handling: The option "widget" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields"...
```

Is there something obvious to add/modify ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to make the field read-only, you should probably use "disabled" option:

```
MyEntity:
    form:
        fields:
            - { property: 'created_at', type_options: { disabled: true } }
```

If this doesn't work for you, can you try to set the form type explicitly?

```
MyEntity:
    form:
        fields:
            - { property: 'created_at', type: 'datetime', type_options: { widget: 'single_text' } }
```

Comment: You can also use the `read_only: true` instead of `disabled`, but I don't know what differences there is between both.

Comment: Yes, I had to add the type parameters. Thanks. Should the doc be updated ?